# ¿Cómo correctamente utilizar el efecto de fadeIn en jQuery sin que cambie el tamaño del elemento?

Tags: jquery

Tengo dos iconos. Quiero que uno desaparezca y el otro aparezca lentamente. Lo intento conseguir con el siguiente código:

```
$('.fa-check-circle-o').hide();

$('.fa-server').css({'opacity':0}).animate({'opacity':1});
```

Pero no funciona, me sale este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).animate is not a function

La razón por la que quiero hacerlo con opacidad es porque no quiero que el elemento desaparezca del todo, sino, simplemente que no sea visible.
 ¿Hay algún modo de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizá es por la versión de jquery que estás usando, ¿Quizas estés usando la versión ligera?. Quiza no contenga todas las funciones como la de animate(), intenta descargarte la más reciente que incorpore esa función, mira también a ver si no has puesto bien la ruta a la libreria.

A mi si me funciona con mi version de jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript "src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#div1').hide();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#div1').css({'opacity':0}).animate({'opacity':1});
            $('#div1').show();
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Este es el div1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Efectivamente, la versión de jQuery era "slim". Muchas gracias. Saludos!

Comment: De nada! Suerte programando